# error while connecting to upstream. Docker compose, NodeJS, Nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a docker compose for Nginx and NodeJS (with React). But get the following error:
`*2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.1, server: ~.*, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.0.2:3000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"`

There were attempts to change the file nginx.conf, adding the depends_on, links parameters, adding various configurations to default.conf, launch from windows and linux, use others ports, all to no avail.
With this configuration, it turned out to collect other projects, everyone works except this, but in structure it is the same as the rest, except for what is here .env file in the root folder "app".

Dockerfile for Node:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# install app dependencies

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install react-scripts -g
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ../app
      dockerfile: ./../docker/dockerfile/node/Dockerfile
    container_name: user-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ../app:/home/node/app
    expose:
      - 3000
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: forensic-nginx
    volumes:
        - ../app:/home/node/app
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
```

default.conf (nginx):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://user-node:3000;
    }
}
```

Project structure:

```
- project
  - app
    - package.json *and more*
  - docker
    - confing
      - nginx
        - default.conf
    - dockerfile
      - node
        - Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
```

At opening localhost:80 get error 502: bad geteway

Comment: I see no network for you app

Comment: try proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000; in nginx config

Answer (score 0):

You need to use docker networks. Change your `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    networks:
      - custom-network
    build:
      context: ../app
      dockerfile: ./../docker/dockerfile/node/Dockerfile
    container_name: user-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ../app:/home/node/app
    expose:
      - 3000
  nginx:
    networks:
      - custom-network
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: forensic-nginx
    volumes:
        - ../app:/home/node/app
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
        - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
      
networks:
  custom-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And you nginx configs should be like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
    }
}
```

If you have a problem using port 80 on localhost, try to change the mapping in nginx part of `docker-compose.yml` to use another port. e.g.

```
    ports:
      - 8088:80
```

Comment: I added networks and changed proxy_pass to the one you advised, but that didn't solve the problem. Also, using path nodejs:3000 the logs, an error occurs (invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6). If use http://nodejs:3000 no error, but 502 response remains.